# Can the Sorcerer's Flexible Casting feature make a "Warlock spell slot" for Eldritch Invocations such as Bewitching Whispers?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, sorcerer, spell-slots, eldritch-invocations

There are certain [invocations](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) a Warlock can get such as Bewitching Whispers which states:

> [...] You can cast compulsion once **using a warlock spell slot.** You can’t do so again until you finish a long rest.

This means that an ordinary Sorcerer/Warlock multiclass could not use spell slots from their Spellcasting feature (Sorcerer spell slots) with Bewitching Whispers. However, the Sorcerer also gets the [Flexible Casting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#FontofMagic-371) feature which states:

> [...] You can transform unexpended sorcery points into one spell slot as a bonus action on your turn [...]

I am aware that [the multiclassing rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Multiclassing) to allow features such as Flexible Casting and Metamagic to apply to Warlock spells as they state:

> Multiclassing allows you to gain levels in multiple classes. Doing so lets you mix the abilities of those classes to realize a character concept that might not be reflected in one of the standard class options.
>
> If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

However it is unclear to me whether spell slots created through Flexible Casting count as Warlock spell slots for the purpose of things such as Bewitching Whispers. Can Flexible Casting spell slots be used with this invocation?

Comment: Related: "[Can you use a Spellcasting spell slot to Eldritch Smite?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112641)"

Answer (score 0):

The invocations which state *using a warlock spell slots* specifically call out using a spell slot from your pact magic class feature.  Spells gained from taking invocations do not count as known or prepared spells so you would not be able to cast them using the Spellcasting class feature, such as the sorcerer's.

When you use the Flexible Casting, you may create warlock spell slots. This feature does not specify what type of spell slot you may or not create.  To create a Warlock spell slot, you would have to expend the appropriate amount of sorcery points depending on your warlock level, and then you can use the invocation.

Refer to: [Can I use Pact Magic spell slots gained on a short rest to gain sorcery points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101813/can-i-use-pact-magic-spell-slots-gained-on-a-short-rest-to-gain-sorcery-points#targetText=Yes%2C%20Flexible%20Casting%20doesn't,gain%20sorcery%20points%20from%20it.)

Comment: "you would have to expend the appropriate amount of sorcery points depending on your warlock level" could you explain what that means? Why can't you create a level X warlock spell slot based on how many Sorcerery Points you want to use up?

Comment: Let's say you are Sorc 7/Warlock 9.  As an 9th level warlock, you **only can have spell slots that are 5th level** (p106 warlock table).  As a Warlock levels up, the level of their spell slots increases.  All of your spell slots are a fixed level for your caster level.  Following the Flexible Casting table (p101) you would have to expend all 7 sorcery points to create 1 of you Warlock spell slots.

Comment: This is true, but if you cast a known spell (from Spellcasting class) using a warlock spell slot (Pact Magic) it will be cast at the warlock's Pact Magic spell slot level.  In my example, if the Sorlock cast *Scorching Ray* via its Warlock spell slot, it is cast at 5th level (generating 3 additional rays).

Comment: Yes I agree with that, but you're saying that Warlock spell slots, even gained through Flexible Casting, *must* be a certain level. However, Sorcerer spell slots can be used to cast Warlock spells without that level requirement. It's just unusual, not necessarily wrong. I believe you're saying a Sorlock *can* make Warlock spell slots but there is a restriction on which ones they can make

Comment: I think spelling out this restriction on the slot's level would help improve your answer (assuming I've understood your point correctly of course)

Comment: I disagree that "This feature does not specify what type of spell slot you may or not create." means "you may create warlock spell slots." The spell slots created by Flexible Casting are not specific to any class. They are simply generic slots of a certain spell level.

Comment: @V2Blast: Especially since being able to actually create *warlock* spell slots leaves a major balance issue: Extra spell slots bought with sorcery points disappear at the end of a long rest, but warlock spell slots are restored on a short rest. The Coffeelock is mildly exploitative as is, but if you say you can burn short-rest restored warlock slots to buy sorcery points (definitely allowed), then use the sorcery points to buy warlock slots (vs. general spellcasting slots), short rest, rinse, repeat, it turns a semi-reasonable linear scaling exploit into an insane exponential scaling exploit.

Comment: Example: Starting from two 5th level Warlock slots and no sorcery points, with enough Sorcerer to buy 5th level slots, one long rest's worth of short rests would end with the Warlock having 130 5th level warlock slots (2->3->5->9->15->26->44->76->130), with four sorcery points left over, many times more effective than the sorcerer's 20th level capstone ability. If RAW allowed it, it would require immediate errata.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: you can't get that progression because sorcery points are limited ("you can never have more sorcery points than shown on the table for your level"). If you have 5th level slots, you're War9+ so you have max 11 sorcery points - only enough to buy back 1 warlock slot.